# install scipy on openshift

Tags: python, scipy, openshift

I would like to install scipy on openshift but I don't know how to do it. I'm an absolute beginner with python and openshift. Therefore it would be great if somebody could provide a step by step explanation on how to proceed.

Comment: You can add in your setup.py file.
install_requires=['Django<=1.4'], include in this list.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I modified the setup.py file and added 'scipy' to the list. How do I run the file?

Comment: $ git push (When we make the push, all task are execute automatically for install and configure Django on Openshift. This executes $ python setup.py install on the remote Openshift for us.)

Answer (score 0):

Either add scipy to your setup.py file or login to openshift `rhc ssh yourapp` and install manually: `pip install scipy`